# FileNotFoundException while Compiling Assembly with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am attempting to compile .cs files using Roslyn at runtime. I believe that I've configured something incorrectly with the required nuget packages.

- I have a method, named "ReadAndCompileSource" which reads the .cs files and compiles them using CSharpCompilation.Create()
- When debugging I cannot step into ReadAndCompileSource, an Exception is thrown as soon as the function is entered:

### Error info

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly         
'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assemblyreference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 

File name: 'System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Reflection.Metadata, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL System.Reflection.Metadata.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

The version of System.Reflection.Metadata that is listed under Project References is versioned at 1.3.0.0

I installed Roslyn for use by doing the following from the nuget console:

```
install-package Microsoft.Net.Compilers

install-package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
```

Attempting to invoke any Roslyn based method in the called method causes the exception.

The version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp installed via the above methods is 1.3.2: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/

Which requires the same version of: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/

Which in turn requires System.Reflection.Metadata >= 1.3.0

Where are these references to System.Reflection.Metadata 1.2.0.0 coming from and how do I get my project back in working order?

I'm confused about this for so many reason:

1. Why is System.Reflection.Metadata 1.2.0.0. being looked for instead of 1.3?
2. Why is Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp listed at 1.3.1 instead of 1.3.2 in the pre-bind information?

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp and it's dependencies countless times and the error persists.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here. I tried using 2.0.0 beta, but now I'm getting: Could not load file or assembly         
'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Sripting, Version=1.3.1.0, ...'. It does not make any sense

Answer (score 0):

I've since solved this issue.

1. Removed all packages related to the issue via the Nuget package manager.
2. Used grep to find all instances of the relevant packages in the project folder (CodeAnalysis & System.Reflection.Metadata) deleted.
3. Deleted any lingering files in the packages folder.
4. Deleted any lingering references in the packages files or .csproj files.
5. Restarted visual studio.
6. Installed the package again using:

`Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 1.3.2`

Seems CodeAnalysis 1.3.1 was installed despite nuget versioning it as 1.3.2 in the Solution browser.